# Should I call .catch on a nested promise?

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I have been asked what promise my `.catch` handles and now I am curious if I am correct or not. I believe, in the following code, that if there is an error in the inner promise, that it will be caught by the `.catch` I have on the calling promise. The question I was asked has me doubting my understanding, and while I don't think I should have a nested catch, I am unsure what the alternative solution would be. I am using native promises in node FYI.

```
  promise1(param1)
    .then((status) => {
      if (status !== 200) {
        return 'Error!';
      }
      promise2(param1, param2)//param2 defined out of this scope
        .then((result) => {
          return 'Yay, result!';
        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return JSON.stringify({'Caught Error': error});
    })
```

I had thought about simply doing something like this but promise2 takes a second param:

```
  promise1(param1)
    .then((status) => {
      if (status !== 200) {
        return 'Error!';
      }
      return param1;
    })
    .then(promise2)
    .catch((error) => {
      return JSON.stringify({'Caught Error': error});
    })
```

So, the question? Should `promise2` have its own `.catch` or would an error here be caught by the `promise1` `.catch`? What is a better way to handle this if I am wrong?

Comment: What about `.then((param1) => promise2(param1, param2))` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe, in the following code, that if there is an error in the inner promise, that it will be caught by the .catch I have on the calling promise.

No. The `catch` will only handle rejections of the promise on which it was invoked.

You can (and *should*) however have that promise resolve with the inner promise, and also reject with an error when the inner promise rejects, by **returning** the promise from the `then` callback.

```
promise1(param1).then(status => {
  if (status !== 200) {
    return 'Error!';
  }
  return promise2(param1, param2);
//^^^^^^
})
.then(result => { // you can unnest this now
  return 'Yay, result!';
})
.catch((error) => {
  return JSON.stringify({'Caught Error': error});
})
```